# Jar file in parse sdk android studio

Tags: android

> > **I am trying to setup parse server in android studio.the problem which i face  i am not able to  found parse jar file and how i add in lib folder??**

**where I found jar file how we connect with parse server**

I refer this tutorial

```
 http://brainwashinc.com/2017/02/17/setting-parse-sdk-android/
```

Downloaded SDK
Put jar file in ‘libs’ dir same level as project ‘java’ dir under src/main
Added Gradle line for jar file to build.gradle (for app module, not project):

Answer (score 0):

I notice the guide you linked doesn't mention specifying the `fileTree` for jars.

In your module-level build.gradle, make sure you have this line:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

This will tell gradle that it should look for `.jar` files in the `libs` directory. Without this line, gradle has no way of finding your jar file.

Please let me know if this solves your issue!

Comment: No still same problem

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are referring to is very old (according to the url path), and contains outdated steps for importing Parse SDK into Android project.

So to answer your question and add little background:

> where I found jar file how we connect with parse server

Parse stopped distributing SDK `.jar` artifacts in 2017, so there is no `.jar` file to download. (I'm not counting old artifacts still hanging around JFrog's Bintray) More background info [here](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/663).

The current way of importing Parse SDK is to add it as a gradle dependency.

Since they're distributing artifacts via Jitpack, which is not included by default in new Android Studio project, you must add this to your **root build.gradle**.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

And then add the library to your **module build.gradle** (In most cases this would mean `app/build.gradle`). You can find latest version on [Jitpack project page](https://jitpack.io/#parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android).

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:latest_version"
}
```

For more information and to avoid similar problems with outdated instructions, I recommend reading the [official docs.](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/)